# Android Temperature Vogella tutorial error

Tags: android

I'm using the vogella tutorial, and I'm almost followed the instructions exactly, but it is sort of giving me an error on text and radiobutton saying it cannot be resolved or it is not in field. I'm really new to Android. Would you please help me out with the code.

```
package convert.activity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private EditText text;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

}

// This method is called at button click because we assigned the name to the
// "On Click property" of the button
public void myClickHandler(View view) {
switch (view.getId()) {
case R.id.button1: 
    RadioButton celsiusButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio0);
    RadioButton fahrenheitButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio1);
    if (text.getText().length() == 0) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter a valid number",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }

    float inputValue = Float.parseFloat(text.getText().toString());
    if (celsiusButton.isChecked()) {
        text.setText(String
                .valueOf(convertFahrenheitToCelsius(inputValue)));
        celsiusButton.setChecked(false);
        fahrenheitButton.setChecked(true);
    } else {
        text.setText(String
                .valueOf(convertCelsiusToFahrenheit(inputValue)));
        fahrenheitButton.setChecked(false);
        celsiusButton.setChecked(true);
    }
    break;
}
}

// Converts to celsius 
private float convertFahrenheitToCelsius(float fahrenheit) {
return ((fahrenheit - 32) * 5 / 9);
}

// Converts to fahrenheit
private float convertCelsiusToFahrenheit(float celsius) {
return ((celsius * 9) / 5) + 32;
}
}
```

Here is my code to activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/myColor" >

    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberSigned|numberDecimal"
     >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="@string/celsius" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/fahrenheit" />
</RadioGroup>


 <Button
android:id="@+id/button1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/calc" 
android:onClick="myClickHandler">
</Button>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The error is on editText1, radio0, radio1 and button1... For all them the error is the same,i.e it cannot be resolved or is not in a field.

Comment: post your activity_main xml

Comment: try to put your findviewbyId for all in onCreate and make their variable public

Comment: Where do You have initializes Your button1,editText1,radio0,radio1?

Answer (score 0):

Here it is...
I used your xml file and it is resolved perfectly

```
EditText text;
RadioButton r1,r2;
    Button b1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    r1 =(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio0);
    r1 =(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio1);
}
```

and do like this

```
b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // your Switch code here

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time on the code, but I'm still getting the same error even after using your code. It is still saying that it cannot be resolved or is not in a field.

Comment: have you copied the string.xml properly from the tutorial.do you any error on that

Comment: do one thing, remove your android:onClick="myClickHandler" from xml file and create your setonclicklister like this b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
   }
  }); 
and put switch code inside, i hope will work

Comment: @Jeet I tried doing it, but it is still showing the same error.

Comment: The error is more of like The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (new OnClickListener(){}) plus the same id cannot be resolved

Comment: make sure the onclicklistner method is inside onCreate...if it is not it will give error related to view...check it

Comment: It is giving me C:\Users\Workspace\Android\FarTemp\res\menu\main.xml:3: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'title' with value '@string/action_settings')

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code it's perfectly working change the activity_main like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
 >

    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberSigned|numberDecimal"
     >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="celsius" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="fahrenheit" />
</RadioGroup>

 <Button
     android:id="@+id/button1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText1"
     android:onClick="myClickHandler"
     android:text="calc" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: try clean your project  project->clean in eclipse

Comment: oh your R.java file would have vanished I dont know how to recover it better do it as a new android project that should work

Comment: Actually one of the fixes were import android.R and when I imported, the same error is returning, i.e id cannot be resolved or is not a field.

Comment: that is I why I suggest you to create a new android project repeat all things once again